# Re-registering user after s/he updates their password

Tags: salesforce

I am using `oauth2` to authenticate user with my salesforce app. But when user updates their password, their `refresh_token` is not valid anymore. How to fetch `access_token` again when they change their password in salesforce?

Comment: can you post more details a refresh_token shouldn't get affected when the password is changed.

Comment: after every 6 hours access_token expires. So we send request for new access_token using refresh_token. Now when user changes is password, I guess he needs to validate our app again. How to do that?

Comment: password changes do not affect the refresh token. post some code.

Answer (score 0):

The access token should be emailed to the user when it's reset. If it's not, you need to manually reset it -- there's no way to access it from Salesforce.

To reset it, go to `[Your Name] | Setup | My Personal Information | Reset Security Token`